# System.Windows.Forms.ListView has white text in "Details" view

Tags: winforms

My listview looks liks where the *view* is *List*. *FullRowSelect* is *true*.

[image]

It has been populated with:

```
lstTest.Items.Add("abc");
lstTest.Items.Add("def");
lstTest.Items.Add("ghi");
```

When I change the style of the listview to *View* is *Details* and *GridLines* is *true*, it looks like this:

[image]

It seems to have no text and some gridlines are missing.

Why?

Comment: Setting HeaderStyle to None made the extra space in the top go away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When View is Details, the ListView object need to have at least one column.

The simplest way is something like

```
lstTest.Columns.Add("Title");
```